# How to turn my one dimensional associative array into multidimensional array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this in PHP returned json of a query result set.

```
    [
       {
          "ailment_id": "1",
          "ailment_name": "Food Poisoning",
          "symptom_name": "Fever",
          "symptom_id": "1",
          "stype_id": "1"
       },
       {
          "ailment_id": "1",
          "ailment_name": "Food Poisoning",
          "symptom_name": "Nausea ",
          "symptom_id": "4",
          "stype_id": "4"
       },
       {
          "ailment_id": "1",
          "ailment_name": "Food Poisoning",
          "symptom_name": "Vomiting",
          "symptom_id": "5",
          "stype_id": "4"
       },
       {
          "ailment_id": "2",
          "ailment_name": "Dengue",
          "symptom_name": "Fever",
          "symptom_id": "1",
          "stype_id": "1"
       },
       {
          "ailment_id": "2",
          "ailment_name": "Dengue",
          "symptom_name": "Headache",
          "symptom_id": "3",
          "stype_id": "2"
       },
       {
          "ailment_id": "2",
          "ailment_name": "Dengue",
          "symptom_name": "Vomiting",
          "symptom_id": "5",
          "stype_id": "4"
       },
       {
          "ailment_id": "2",
          "ailment_name": "Dengue",
          "symptom_name": "Joint Pain",
          "symptom_id": "7",
          "stype_id": "5"
       },
       {
          "ailment_id": "3",
          "ailment_name": "Flu",
          "symptom_name": "Fever",
          "symptom_id": "1",
          "stype_id": "1"
       },
       {
          "ailment_id": "3",
          "ailment_name": "Flu",
          "symptom_name": "Headache",
          "symptom_id": "3",
          "stype_id": "2"
       },
      {
      "ailment_id": "3",
      "ailment_name": "Flu",
      "symptom_name": "Chronic Cough",
      "symptom_id": "2",
      "stype_id": "1"
      },
   {
      "ailment_id": "4",
      "ailment_name": "Common Cold",
      "symptom_name": "Sore Throat",
      "symptom_id": "6",
      "stype_id": "1"
   }
]
```

I would like to group them into this, the one of the id as the parent key, with value of name. duplicate parent key will cascade, just assign the children into the same parent. 
I'm not sure about the formatting, i guess you can understand:

```
{
   "1": {
      "stype" : "1",
      "child" : { "1": {
                "symptom_id": "1",
                "symptom_name": "Fever",
                "child" : {
                    "1": {
                            "ailment_id": "1",
                            "ailment_name": "Food Poisoning" 
                         },
                    "2": {
                            "ailment_id": "2",
                            "ailment_name": "Dengue"
                        },
                    "3": {
                            "ailment_id": "3",
                            "ailment_name": "Flu"
                            }
                    }
                },
                 "4": {
                  "symptom_id": "6",
                  "symptom_name": "Sore Throat",
                  "child" : {
                     "4": {
                            "ailment_id": "4",
                            "ailment_name": "Common Cold"
                            }
                        }
                    }
        },
    "4" {           
      "stype" : "4",
      "child" : { "4" :  {
                "symptom_name": "Nausea",
                "symptom_id": "4",
                "child" : {
                        "ailment_id": "1",
                        "ailment_name": "Food Poisoning",
                            }
                    }
            }
        },
    "2" {
      "stype" : "2",
      "child" : { "3" : {
                "symptom_name": "Headache",
                "symptom_id": "3",
                "child" : {     
                        "ailment_id": "2",
                        "ailment_name": "Dengue",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, .... and so on}
```

Is there anyway i can do this in PHP/Jquery? I will use the final array to cast them into a multiple select chain of 3 multiple select box. Any tips on that?

EDIT: what i have tried? Something like this.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$sid = $row["symptom_id"];
$sname = $row["symptom_name"];
$stype = $row["stype_id"];
$aname = $row["ailment_name"];
$aid = $row["ailment_id"];
?>
var selectValues2 = { "<?php echo $stype; ?>" : 
                                        {   
                                            "<?php echo $sname ?>" : 
                                                    [ 
                                                    "<?php echo $aid ?>",
                                                    "<?php echo $aname; ?>" 
                                                    ]
                                        }
                    };
  <?php 
  }
  ?>
```

Doesn't work well..

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your post shows what you have and what you want.

Comment: check out the EDIT section.. my bad

Comment: How many user names do you have? This is the same as questions you posted as another user